# combine XML with XSL and show with some style

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am try to create XML file that combine with XML and XSL but I doesn't work well.
The all code is copy from w3schools and it feel like don't have any XSL file inside it

I share my links to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) xml file and some pictures

It should look like that that

[image]

I am show it like that no style at all (from fireFox and chrome)

[image]

The codes: (same like website)

[image]

[image]

How I should fix that issue and why it happened
on there website it work perfectly.
Thanks for help :-)

full code XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
    <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS</company>
    <price>8.10</price>
    <year>1973</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Maggie May</title>
    <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Pickwick</company>
    <price>8.50</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Romanza</title>
    <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.80</price>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Black angel</title>
    <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Mega</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist>Many</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Grammy</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1999</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>For the good times</title>
    <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Mucik Master</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Big Willie style</title>
    <artist>Will Smith</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
    <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1971</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Soulsville</title>
    <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
    <country>Norway</country>
    <company>WEA</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>The very best of</title>
    <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Island</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Stop</title>
    <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>A and M</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
    <artist>T`Pau</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Siren</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Private Dancer</title>
    <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Capitol</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Midt om natten</title>
    <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Medley</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
    <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>DECCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1991</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>The dock of the bay</title>
    <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Stax Records</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1968</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Picture book</title>
    <artist>Simply Red</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Elektra</company>
    <price>7.20</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Red</title>
    <artist>The Communards</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>London</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Unchain my heart</title>
    <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>EMI</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Try to reduce samples to a minimum to demonstrate the problem. How do you try to run the XSLT when it fails? Browsers except IE do not longer support `file` URI based `<?xml-stylesheet?>` based XSLT, unless you change their settings.

Comment: Hey @MartinHonnen thank for comment I am run it on fireFox with default setting and it show like pictures and the cod long because I did copy paste from w3schools to confirm same code. I add picture with files name XML and XSL (I try to edit XSL file to XSLT and same problem) I just want see it with style like on w3schools website

Comment: We can't see and read the complete code if you post pictures, build a minimal example and insert the code as code samples? Do you have an `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?>` in the XML? Do you load the files over HTTP(S) (which should work) or from the local file system (which does not work unless you change Firefox settings)? Or do you run the XSLT with JavaScript? What does the error console (F12) in Firefox show?

Comment: I edit and add full code XML file. You can see code it same like w3schools so no I don't have <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?> because on website doesn't have that it run like that (file:///C:/Users/Name/Desktop/stackoverflow/xml.xml)

Comment: If you want the browser to automatically apply an XSLT to an XML document you need to associate the XSLT with the XML using a processing instruction `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="yourxsl.xsl"?>` before the root element of the XML. However, due to security restrictions, that does not work in Chrome, Firefox, Chromium based Edge if the XML is loaded from the file system, it only works over HTTP(S). The w3cschools site doesn't need the processing instruction as they apply the XSLT server-side with code and just send the resulting HTML to the browser.

Comment: now I have on console 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/Lichay/Desktop/stackoverflow/xsl.xsl. (Reason: CORS request not http).' so how can I run it? Edit: i try to run it with 'https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html' website but i show tags instead style

Comment: Over HTTP(S). Or by changing a setting in Firefox, check previous questions with the relevant answers or comments, I forgot how the setting is named.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228833/discussion-between-lolix-and-martin-honnen).